# Artifactory remove /api/gems/gems from url with nginx

Tags: nginx, artifactory

I have an Artifactory server as a gem repository. In order to use the local server I need to setup my gem sources with this ugly url.

`gem source -a gems.example.com/api/gems/gems/`

I'd like to remove the need for developers to know the URI `/api/gems/gems/` so they can simply access `gems.example.com`

```
server {
  listen       *:443 ssl default;
  server_name   artifactory.example.com gems.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/artifactory.example.com.crt.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/artifactory.example.com.key.pem;
  location / {
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ ) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/$1; }
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_read_timeout 2400s;
  }
```

A rewrite would work, however the nginx configs already have the following `if`, and nginx does not allow for multiple conditionals.

not valid:

```
if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ && $server_name) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/$1; }
```

How can I eliminate `/api/gems/gems/` from the url `https://gems.example.com/api/gems/gems/` ?

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple server blocks like so:

Note that the second server block has the following changes.
- server_name
- no 'default' on the listen line
- proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/artifactory.conf

```
server {
  listen       *:443 ssl default;
  server_name   artifactory.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/artifactory.example.com.crt.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/artifactory.example.com.key.pem;
  location / {
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ ) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/$1; }
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_read_timeout 2400s;
  }
  # ....
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/artifactory-gems.conf

```
server {
  listen       *:443 ssl;
  server_name   gems.example.com;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/certs/artifactory.example.com.crt.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/private/artifactory.example.com.key.pem;
  location / {
    if ( $request_uri ~ ^/(.*)$ ) { proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/$1; }
    proxy_cookie_path ~*^/.* /;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/gems/gems/;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_read_timeout 2400s;
  }
  # ....
```

Note `/gems/gems` corresponds to the virtual repo on artifactory called 'gems'. If you have multiple gem repositories, you will need to add a vhost for every repo.